# Overriding CCNode setPosition resulting in strange results

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this problem with the setPosition of my CCNode subclass "Unit".

The subclass has a CCSprite property and a CCProgressTimer property. I want it to behave so that when I call Unit setPosition, it would move my sprite and my progressTimer to that position with an offset.

```
- (void) setPosition:(CGPoint)position
{
    [super setPosition:position];
    self.health_bar.position = ccpAdd(position, ccp(0,-10));
    self.sprite.position = ccpAdd(position, ccp(0,10));
}
```

What actually happens is that the progress bar gets moved to where I want it to, but the sprite is moved more and more away as you set the position further away from (0,0).

[image: setPosition near origin]
[image: setPosition further away]

Answer (score 0):

Needed to convertToNodePosition

Comment: So that this helps future readers, please provide more information than this. Describe what you did and how that fixed the problem.